# WordPress shortcodes not working in posts

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am making a custom theme with shortcodes. The theme is ready, but now I need to make the shortcodes.

The problem is that the shortcodes don't work in my posts, they are only visible on my pages. When I add a shortcode in my post, the post displays nothing.

Here is the shortcode code:

```
function rss_subscribe_link() {  
return 'Enjoy what you\'re reading? <a href="http://www.matthewbarby.com/feed/">Subscribe to our RSS feed here now</a>.'; } 

add_shortcode('rss-subscribe', 'rss_subscribe_link');
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Greets,

Joren

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if your post content is displayed via `get_the_content()` which is a function that returns the content without applying the default filters (wpautop, do_shortcode etc) that are applied normally when you use `the_content()`. Could you confirm if this is the case?